# Отдельный конфиг файл Nginx

Tags: nginx

Как сделать так чтобы для каждого сайта был отдельный nginx конфиг внутри корневой папки сайта? то есть siteA/nginx.conf и siteBnginx.conf?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, аналога `.htaccess` в nginx нету, а если пытаться его эмулировать с помощью каких-нибудь include'ов, получится не очень безопасно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Теоретически, можно вынести настройки секции server для сайта в отдельный файл и поместить его в корневую папку сайта. Но:

1. Так можно вынести настройки только уровня server. Настройки более высоких уровней (например, http), вынести не получится - они общие для всех сайтов
2. Принципиальная разница с Apache - все настройки читаются только один раз, при старте/рестарте nginx. Динамически вносить изменения для сайта, как это сделано в .htaccess, не получится. Дать администратору сайта право рестартовать nginx - сложно и совсем уж небезопасно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, поступить так:

```
http {

    ...

    include /var/www/*/*.nginx.conf;

 }
```

Comment: Можно, но могут быть конфликтующие настройки для разных сайтов.